# Convert multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I convert the below array to look like the one right below. I am trying to use array_map but i am confused on how to write the function.

```
array(3) {
  ["award_year"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "1999-01"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "2010-02"
  }
  ["award_title_user"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "tt"
  }
  ["award_description_user"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "ddd"
  }
}
```

This what i am trying to achieve:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["award_year"]=>
    string(7) "2010-02"
    ["award_title_user"]=>
    string(2) "tt"
    ["award_description_user"]=>
    string(3) "ddd"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["award_year"]=>
    string(7) "1999-01"
    ["award_title_user"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["award_description_user"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($oldArr as $key=>$row) {
   foreach($row as $index=>$item) {
       $newArr[$index][$key] = $item;
   }   
}
```

this will solve it, but no checks if data is valid as you mentioned

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! I am not sure what you are trying to say about "no checks if data is valid". Do you foresee any problem?

Comment: I just said that if you can promise that your arrays are build as you said, there will be no problems, but if you are not sure, Ill add some checks "isset" or something and than place a default value or something

Answer (score 0):

First things first, @tzook-bar-noy's answer is a better answer in this case, and I am not even advocating the approach I am going to detail here.

When dealing with arrays, I always try to avoid generic loops (ie: `foreach()`) if I can, instead using the more functional-programming approach that you mention in your question: using functions like `array_map()`. However the functional-programming functions are very focused in what they do (which is their benefit: they make your code [Cleaner](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882)), so to use them: you kinda gotta be wanting to do the specific operation they offer.

`array_map()` has a drawback for your purposes here, in that the mapped array has the same keys in the same order as the original array, which is not what you want here. You need to both turn your original array "inside out", but the ordering of the resultant array you want is the reverse of the original data. Not a good fit for `array_map()`.

It's doable with `array_map()`, but it's like using a flathead screwdriver when you really need a Philips.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$awards = [
    "award_year" => ["1999-01", "2010-12"],
    "award_title_user" => ["2", "tt"],
    "award_description_user" => ["2", "ddd"]
];

$remappedAwards = array_map(function($year, $title, $description){
    return [
        "award_year" => $year,
        "award_title_user" => $title,
        "award_description_user" => $description
    ];
}, $awards["award_year"], $awards["award_title_user"], $awards["award_description_user"]);

$remappedAwards = array_reverse($remappedAwards);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($remappedAwards);
echo "</pre>";
```

Obviously I've hardcoded the key names in here too which is less than ideal. One *could* contrive a generic approach, but by then we'd be so far beyond the actual intent of `aaray_map()` that the code complexity would be getting daft.

In other languages wherein these array-iteration functions are a bit better implemented (say JS or CFML) one might be able to come up with a half-decent answer with a `.reduce()` ([JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [CFML](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArrayReduce)) kind of operation. However PHP's [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) (and its other array-iteration methods) are hamstrung by their poor implementation as they only pass the *value* to the callback. They really need to pass at least the index as well, and (less-often-useful, but handy sometimes ~) the array itself as additional arguments to make them anything more than a proof-of-concept. IMO, obviously (I'm biased, I do more JS & CFML than I do PHP, so my expectations are set higher).

Bottom line: `array_map()` was not a good fit for your requirement here, but I applaud your efforts for thinking to us it as the function-programming approach to array manipulation is definitely a better approach than generic looping where the requirement matches the functionality.

Comment: @anil-astrio, if you're at all interested: on my blog I investigate using `array_reduce()` to answer this question: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/11/php-cfml-mapping-and-reducing.html